# Portforwarding : Virtualbox NAT connecting (Guest to Host)

Tags: virtualbox, portforwarding

I am using Macbook air and its OS is OS X 10.8.5, installed win7 with virtual box. 
And developing web application at win7 virtual box, I want to port forward virtualbox
port to host port. So that I could test app on the host and also to the mobile phone 
using same wifi.

[image]

First I didn't type host and guest ip and put the port value 8000.
I figured out guest ip and host ip by writing "ipconfig" and "ifconfig".

After running server of guest, I wrote the web address on host browser like below,

http://[guest ip]:8000/

But cannot load the web page of guest.

What is the problem?

And also if I want to load the web application of virtualbox to mobile phone

How could I do it?

Though it looks a bit silly, It would be glad to have an advice.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you to work that way, you can develop your web application right in your OSX, it would be much easier.

But if you have to do that way. Then first, because your network configuration is NAT, your VM will has an private IP like: 10.0.2.15, you need to forward to port to access, it likes:

[image]

From the above image, I forward port 2022 to 22, 2080 to 80 (web server)
So let's say your web is running at the same port 80, here is the URL for you to access to your web: 127.0.0.1:2080

BTW for me i don't like to work through the port forwarding, I prefer to configure my VM using "host only". By that way you can have an ip like 192.168.x.x and you can forget the port forwarding. You can read it more from here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Hope it helps you.